# AS3: Date Object Not Returning Month Correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, date

Anyone else having this issue while trying to name a file with the current date and time.

```
redeemedImgName:String = "soemtext_" + datToday.getFullYear() + "-" +  datToday.getMonth() + "-" + datToday.getDay() + "-" + datToday.getHours() + "-" + datToday.getMinutes() + "-" + datToday.getSeconds();
```

Today is 4/2/2015, but I got the following file name:

```
"sometext_2015-3-4-15-32-10.jpg"
```

Yesterday, I was receiving 3/32/2015.  Again, anyone else experiencing this issue?

Please advise,
rikixass

Comment: It's not an issue, as per the Date docs months returned are zero based so January is 0 for example.

Answer (score 1):

`datToday.getDay()` returns an integer 0-7 corresponding to the day of the week.  What you are looking for is `datToday.getDate()`, which returns the actual calendar number of the day.  The months are zero based, so you'd get 3 for April, 4 for may etc.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html

Comment: Sly, why do you keep editing my answer?  You haven't added anything of value to my original answer.